# Transform rows and column variables using tidyr and other options

Tags: r, transform, tidyr

I have the iris data set with below format,

```
Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
setosa          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
setosa          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
setosa          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
setosa          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
setosa          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
setosa          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4
```

I wish to transform it to the below format,

```
Species  Part Length Width
  setosa Petal    1.4   0.2
  setosa Petal    1.4   0.2
  setosa Petal    1.3   0.2
  setosa Petal    1.5   0.2
  setosa Petal    1.4   0.2
  setosa Petal    1.7   0.4
```

I am able to achieve it using tidyr package. Code below,

```
iris.wide <- iris %>%
  gather(key, value, -Flower, -Species) %>%
  separate(key, c("Part", "Measure"), "\\.") %>%
  spread(Measure, value)
```

But I just feel its a lot of code/steps use gather, seperate and spread functions.

I am looking for suggestions to do it in a more better/near way, if any.

Comment: oops it got removed in copy paste

Comment: Are you taking the mean or sum of those values ?

Comment: It is more straightfoward with `data.table` i.e. `melt(as.data.table(iris), measure = patterns("Length", "Width"), value.name = c("Length", "Width"))`

Comment: the flower column got removed in copy paste. Please imagine flower column in output data set, which is a number to indicate the flower.

Comment: an adaptation @akrun's comment to get the exact desired outcome: `melt(as.data.table(iris), id = 'Species', measure.vars = patterns('Length','Width'), variable.name = 'Part', value.name = c('Length', 'Width'))[, Part := c('Sepal','Petal')[Part]][]`